# Select table from <select> that contains distinct from session

Tags: php, sql, sorting, session, input

I have problem to get all distinction from session to create  based on that.

form_kuesioner_pengelola.php

```
id_prov |  idkab   | detail  
1           | 2           | abc..    
1           | 2           | abc2..  
1           | 3           | cde..  
1           | 4           | xyz..
```

How do I create < option > that contain distinction of idkab so it can acts like search to table when session set the time user login (in this case which is '1').

```
$id_prov = $_SESSION['id_prov'];
$level = $_SESSION['level'];


$sql="select idFormKuesionerPengelola, idprov, FormCode, kecamatan, kelurahan, provinsi, kabupaten from form_kuesioner_pengelola left join mst_province on form_kuesioner_pengelola.idprov = mst_province.id_tbl_mst_prov join mst_kab on form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab = mst_kab.id_tbl_mst_kab WHERE mst_province.id_prov='$id_prov'";
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'kabupaten'){
    $sql .= " order by form_kuesioner_pengelola.idkab";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'detail'){
    $sql .= " order by form_kuesioner_pengelola.detail";
}
$rdata=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
echo "<table class='table1' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";

echo "<tr> <th>No.</th> <th><a href='list_kuesioner_pengelola.php?sort=idform'>ID Form</a></th> <th>Provinsi</th> <th><a href='list_kuesioner_pengelola.php?sort=kabupaten'>Kabupaten</a></th> <th><a href='list_kuesioner_pengelola.php?sort=detail'>detail</a></th> "
```

I can only achieve this for now.. sort by table field

thanks

Comment: It kinda sounds like you want to know how to select all the distinct values in IDKAB and put them in a combo/drop down list so that your user can choose one, and you can then use that to search the table (`where idkab = $what_the_user_chose` ). If true, that's too broad a question for stackoverflow; we're here to help you with your work, rather than do it for you

Comment: yes that is. can you give related question for that? im just too confused that i have 30 id_prov and want to do distinct [IDKAB] based on idprov.

Comment: or can you suggest me what to do first?